# Is there a way to show the git log graph from the HEAD to a commit that was made by a specific user?

Tags: git, git-log

We have our daily build done by a automated user, which will make an empty commit to the repo with the build information in the message.

I was wondering if I could either:

1. Get the last log entry (or *n* log entries) from where I am currently in the repo that was committed by that automated user and/or
2. Show a graph from HEAD to that same automated user's commit which shows all users commits that were done in between.

Are either possible just using git commands, or do I have to do some external processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I've added some (long) background below, for general usefulness.

(To find commit(s) made by a particular user, use `--author=`.  This works with most revision-walking operations, since it's implemented by `git log` and `git rev-list` and other Git commands use these.)

Consider using `git log --ancestry-path --graph [options] automated-commit..HEAD`, but with some caveats:

- There may not *be* a path between the automated commit and the `HEAD` commit.
- If there is a path, it might go the other way, if the `HEAD` commit is behind the automated commit.

Note also that Git will omit the boundary (stop-point) commit—that is, in `A..B`, Git is really doing `B ^A`, so it includes commit `B` but excludes commit `A`.  If you want commit `A` included as well, you have several options:

- Back up one commit for the stop-point: use `^A^`, assuming `A` has only one parent, or `^A^@` if `A` could be a merge commit (`A^@` means "all parents of `A`, and the leading `^` is from expanding out the `A..B` form to its internal `B ^A` form for generality here).
- Or, use `--boundary` to have Git include boundary commits.  Git tends to add too many boundary commits, in my experience, but `--ancestry-path` might eliminate this since `--ancestry-path` augments the usual `A..B` by requiring that displayed commits have `A` as an ancestor.

(Bottom line: this should work as long as there is a path and you get the order correct.  Making it really useful, and handling your various edge cases, is harder.)

## Background: how `git log` and its sister `git rev-list` work

Commits, in Git, are known and found by their true names, which are their hash IDs.  The hash ID of each commit is a big ugly string such as `8a0ba68f6dab2c8b1f297a0d46b710bb9af3237a` (which is [a commit in the Git repository for Git itself](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a0ba68f6dab2c8b1f297a0d46b710bb9af3237a).)  Each ID is unique: no other commit can ever have this ID.  They aren't actually random, but they *seem* random and are not useful to humans, so *we* use names like `master` and `develop`.  Git keeps a table, constantly being updated, that says, e.g., *`master` means `8a0ba68f6...`*, and so on.

Using these table entries, we say that `master` *points to* some commit.  Let's say that `master` points to some commit whose hash ID we've shortened to one uppercase letter, `G`:

```
G   <--master
```

(you'll see in a moment why I put `master` to the right).

Adding a new commit to a branch just updates the name-to-hash-ID mapping: you create a new commit, Git assigns it a unique hash ID, and if you're on `master`, Git updates the table entry for `master` to hold that new hash ID:

```
H   <--master
```

This means that the commit to which some branch name points—the arrow stored in a branch name—*changes* over time.  That's how Git finds the latest commit for that branch.  By definition, whatever commit hash is saved for that branch name, that commit *is* the tip of that branch.

Now, each commit *also* holds some number of *parent* hash IDs—usually exactly one.  What *this* means is that, given a table that says *`master` is `a1234...`, and a commit `a1234...` that says *my parent is `0f987...`*, Git knows that `a1234...` is the *latest* commit on master.  Git then *reads* commit `a1234...` to find the *second-latest* commit on master, which is `0f987...`.  So `master` points to the latest commit, `a1234...`, and that commit points to its parent, and its parent points to the grandparent, and so on.

This means that starting from the *end*, Git can work *backwards* through the chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

The name `master` lets Git find commit `H`, which finds commit `G`, which finds `F`, and so on, backwards through history.  *History* is therefore just *the string of all commits, starting at the end and working backwards.*

The special name `HEAD` usually holds the *name of a branch*.  There are two fairly obvious ways to draw this, one with `HEAD` pointing to the branch name, and then the branch name pointing to the commits:

```
                      HEAD
                       |
                       v
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

That's more accurate in some ways, but not very compact.  For compactness, I like to omit the arrows inside the commits themselves.  These can never change (unlike the branch name arrows)—nothing about *any* commit can ever change.  So if we see:

```
...--F--G--H
```

we know it's `H` that points to `G`, and `G` that points to `F`, and so on.  Then I have the arrow coming from `master` to find `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

and to this I *attach* the word `HEAD` to say that this is the *current* branch, so that if we have more branches, we can see what's going on:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Here, we have two branches; the name `develop` points to commit `J`, whose parent is `I`, which leads back to `G` and `F` and so on, while the name `master` points to `H`, which leads back to `G` and `F` and so on.

#### Aside: which branch(es) is some commit "on"?

If we look at the above, we can say that commit `H` is on `master` and `J` is on `develop`.  That's pretty natural since those names point directly to those commits.  But what about commit `G`, which branch or branches is it on?

Some systems pick one answer and stick with it.  Git is different.  Git says that `G` is on *every* branch that can get to `G`, so it's on *both* `master` *and* `develop`.  To get to `G` from `master`, we go back one hop.  To get to `G` from `develop`, we go back two hops.  Either way, we land on `G`.

#### `git log` and `git rev-list` just follow these arrows

Given some starting point, like `master` or `develop` or even `HEAD`, what `git log` does is, to put it a little too simply:

- Show the commit it has right now, whatever that is.
- Move on to the parent commit.
- Repeat until we run out of commits.

This description isn't *wrong*, but it lacks a lot of important detail.  The first complication arises with merges.  Let's take our graph-so-far and *merge* `develop` back into `master`, using:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge develop
```

Without going into *how* `git merge` works—that's its own separate question and answer (but already asked many times)—we end up with this graph:

```
...--F--G--H---K   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Commit `K` is a *merge commit*, which means it has at least *two* parents.  The two parents of `K` are `H` (as usual) and also `J` (because we merged commit `J`, as found via the name `develop`).

After `git log` shows commit `K`, which commit should it move on to?  It could pick either one.  What it really does is put *both* commits into a queue, then pick one and show it and put that one's parent into the queue, if it hasn't already done that.  Then it picks another one from the queue, and repeats:

- Initially, put the commit(s) listed on the command line into the queue.  If you didn't specify any particular commits, `git log` uses `HEAD`.  Then, in a loop:

  - Show the commit that's at the front of the queue.
  - If the commit's parents aren't already queued and haven't already been shown, put them all in the queue.
- Repeat the loop until the queue is empty (or the user quits).

Because there is a queue, there's some magic to manage who's at the *front*.  By default, this is handled by sorting-by-date/time-stamp, but you can change that with various sort options.

This means that Git will, by default for `git log`, *first* show commit `K`, then *one of* `H` or `J`, then *one of* `H` or `I`, then *the other of* `H` or `I`, and now the queue has only `G` in it so the order is clear (`G` then `F`).  Note that Git can't get to `I` without going through `J`, so `J` definitely comes out before `I`, but Git can get to `H` in two ways, so we don't know exactly where `H` comes out.

#### Restrictions on what gets queued and/or shown

No matter what else you do, `git log` and `git rev-list` *always* have to walk through this priority queue, picking the next commit to show, adding parent commits to the queue, and looping.  But you can control *which parents get added* and/or *which commits actually get shown*.

The *which parents* control knobs are:

- `--first-parent`: this says that when the walking code hits a merge commit, it should add only the *first* parent of that merge.  In our example, merge commit `K` has two parents, with `H` being the first, so with `--first-parent`, `git log` walks from `K` to `H` to `G`, ignoring the commits we merged from the side branch.
- `--no-walk`: this says that the walking code should do nothing: never add any parents.  That makes the loop stop pretty quickly: we see only the commit(s) listed on the command line.

The *which to show* knobs are much more complicated as there are a lot of them.  Here, I'm going to ignore all the pathspec oriented ones, and look at just `--author` and `--committer`, and the `--max-count` / `-n` number.  The first two tell Git: *Show the commit only if the author or committer is the one listed.*  (You can list more than one `--author` or `--committer`; Git will show the commit if it matches any of the names you specify.)

Note that the *walk* is still based on the graph.  It's just that you don't *see* commits that don't have the right author or committer.

Meanwhile, the `--max-count` aka `-n` number tells Git that it should exit the loop after *showing* some number of commits.  With `-n 5 --author automatic@local`, for instance, Git will walk all the commits as usual, showing whichever ones are authored by `automatic@local`, but once it's shown five such commits, stop.  Of course, it will stop early if there are fewer commits.

#### When to use `git log` vs `git rev-list`

The `git log` command is what Git calls *porcelain:* it's supposed to be all clean and shiny and attractive to users.  As such, it's something users can customize.  You can set output colors, options like `log.decorate`, and other useful (to humans) items.

The `git rev-list` command is much more strict and boring.  It is what Git calls *plumbing:* a program meant to produce output that's not necessarily good for humans, but is useful for other *computer programs*.  It behaves the same way, regardless of who *runs* it, so that a program that needs some information that `git rev-list` can provide, can get it in a consistent way.  (That program can then go on to be all fancy and human-oriented, if you like.)  What `git rev-list` produces, by default, is just a series of commit hashes, which are the hash IDs of the commits that the same `git log` command would have shown.

For whatever reason, `git log` will start from `HEAD` by default, while `git rev-list` won't.  So, to convert a `git log` command (that you're testing to see if you get the right commits) to a `git rev-list` one (that you'll use in some other program), you sometimes need to add `HEAD` to the arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, how do I get the `automated-commit` hash?

Comment: That's the easy part since `--author` or `--committer` finds it for you. (Use `git rev-list -n <number> --author=<author>`, etc.)

Comment: So like this:  `git log --graph --pretty=format:'blah' --ancestry-path $(git log --author=builduser -1 --pretty=format:'%H')^..HEAD`, where `blah` is whatever you want to be displayed in your graph and `builduser` is the name of the automated user.  Great.  Works for me. :)

Comment: With `git rev-list` you must tell it where to start; it works backwards from there, like `git log`, but unlike `git log`, without a starting point, it doesn't default to `HEAD`.

Comment: Um. Thanks. Not exactly sure what you were trying to teach me here. Except for `rev-list` requiring both start _and_ end points _and_ that it's a plumbing command, I pretty much knew everything else. Still, thanks. I'm sure others will appreciate it.  Unless you think I'm not understanding something of importance, or is this a comment on my use of a porcelain command to find the hash?

Comment: Ah, for some reason I didn't see both your comments. But it's good to have reference stuff for others, later. I'll tweak the wording at the top a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> Get the last log entry (or n log entries) from where I am currently in the repo that was committed by that automated user

Consider the `--author` or `--committer` option of `git log` for that:

> ```
> --author=<pattern>, --committer=<pattern>
> ```
>
> Limit the commits output to ones with author/committer header lines that match the specified pattern (regular expression). With more than one `--author=<pattern>`, commits whose author matches any of the given patterns are chosen (similarly for multiple `--committer=<pattern>`).

So, to show the last 5 commits by `that-user` on the branch you have currently checked out, you could do

```
git log --pretty=fuller --author='that-user' -5
```

Comment: Doesn't that give you the 5 most recent committed items in the repo, not from where I am?

Comment: Unless you specified `--all`, no, that command will show you the last 5 commits by the specified author from your checked-out branch.